# Does using a parenthesis make a difference when using && or ||?

Tags: java, logic, comparison, and-operator

Is one preferred over the other? If so, why?

```
 int value1 = 1;
 int value2 = 2;

 if (value1 == 1 && value2 == 2) {
    System.out.println("works");
    }

 if ((value1 == 1) && (value2 == 2)) {
    System.out.println("works");
    }
```

Expected matches actual results. Both print the string "works"

Comment: No difference whatsoever.

Comment: But using parentheses does indicate your intent, so that the next person looking at the code doesn't have to try to decide whether the original author (you) understood the order of precedence. (Not necessarily in this case, but especially when mixing && and || in the comparisons).

Comment: technically no difference in this case, But if you want  a general rule i'd recommend braces and also to swap the oparands. 

(( 1 == value1) && ( 2 == value2))

Comment: Please consult https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @Aubin thats actually what I've been using

Comment: reason: boxing, casts ... and so on can provide bad surprises.

Comment: My preference is to omit most superfluous parentheses,  Extra punctuation adds visual clutter and therefore makes it harder to read.  Anyone who expects to use Java professionally (or practically any other similar language) ought to know at a glance that, for example, arithmetic operators bind tighter than relational operators which bind tighter than logical operators.  This is not an edict to always use minimal bracketing; simply an admonition that making simple cases look more complicated is negatively useful.  And yes, I realize this contradicts the 'establishment view'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parentheses are useful to group your logical expressions just as you would in a mathematical expression.

It makes the order of precedence clearer.

In this case they are not needed as you are working with only 2 expressions.

But what happens on a similar case using both `OR` and `AND`?

It can lead to an ambiguous case:

```
if (a && b || c)
```

Will be interpreted as:

```
if ((a && b) || c)
```

When you wanted the expression to be treated as:

```
if (a && (b || c))
```

Comment: Would parenthesis create a precedence over which expression is evaluated first despite it being left --> right, similar to mathematics?

Comment: @NishGrewal When you say *"which expression is evaluated"*, you seem to be mixing *associativity* (left-to-right vs right-to-left) and *operator precedence* (e.g. `*` before `+`) with *order of evaluation* (which is *always* left-to-right).

Comment: In Java, [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) says that `&&` is evaluated before `||`, the same way `*` is evaluated before `+`, so your *"May be interpreted as"* is incorrect. It is however a good idea to always use parentheses when mixing `&&` and `||`, since too many people don't know the precedence of those operators.

Comment: @Andreas thank you for clarifying, I really appreciate you helping me out.

Comment: I do know the precedencs and that &&. binds stonger. But never the less I find myself every once in while confronted with some "miracolous" errormessages, which could have been avoided by simple putting braces. So braces are highly recommended.

Comment: Parentheses: ```()```.  Braces: ```{}```.  Brackets: ```[]```.

Comment: For literally the case you gave, ```a && b || c```, then I wouldn't bother.  It's simple enough and easy to read.  But for more complicated conditionals, I probably would.  The advice I'd give here is to develop some taste and use your judgement as to what is appropriate; in the long run this will serve you better than following a set of rules. Or to say it differently, if it looks ambiguous *to you* then add parentheses, otherwise don't. Aspire to craftsmanship!

Comment: Well most people are sloopy. Sure I am . You have to provide code in time - sure...  But nowadays when I get certain errormessages I first put braces(parentheses ;) )  in my expression, do some formatting and only if that didn't help I start thinking about what went wrong.

Comment: @Andreas edited my answer to clarify operator precedence. That way when someone else comes to this answer in the future doesn't get an erroneous example.